# How to get only one column-set of array-data (vuejs2 getters)

Tags: vuejs2, getter, vuex

My efWezlow array:

```
[{"adres":"Something","w17_18":60,"w16_17":61,"w15_16":62,"w14_15":48,"w13_14":null},
...{}]
```

I have getters:

```
export default {
   fil_adres: state => {
     return state.efWezlow.filter(efWezel => efWezel.adres)
   }
}
```

and in mounted:
get data by

`this.$store.getters.fil_adres`

My array getters via Vuex

```
fil_adres: Array[9]
0: Object
   adres: "Something"
   w17_18: 62
   w16_17: 72
   w15_16: 65
1: Object
...
8: Object
```

**And big question how can I get only column 'adres' from array:**

`[{adres, w17_18, w16_17, w15_16},...{}]`

Is it possible?

Filter on getters don't  cut off rest of 'columns' so I get whole array despite want one column.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand, but that "adres" column, wouldn't that be just getting the keys of each object (which you could do with Object.keys or a `for in` loop with the hasownproperty condition?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in `getters`, and I'm assuming you don't want a list of objects, instead, an array that only contains values of `adres`, a `map` suffices:

```
export default {
  fil_adres: state => state.efWezlow.map(item => item.adres)
}
```

Comment: It was this. Map in getters :) Thanks! I'm very sorry but I have no reputation to vote. So forgive me I didn't vote.

Comment: Glad I can help. And you can upvote, only downvoting uses your reputation, and I'll just be as glad even if you just check my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
export default {

fil_adres(state){
 return state.efWezlow.map(el=>{
    return el.adres;
})

}
}
```

Comment: This expresion works excellent too, so thank You very much. I'm very sorry but I have no reputation to vote. So forgive me I didn't vote.

Comment: Happy to help :)